# Visual Studio c# : Trying to send a string to another form

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I'm working on a school project.
This is the code from first form, out of which i'm trying to send a string:

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ime=input_Ime.Text;
        var frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.imee = ime;
    }
```

"Registracija" is the name of my first form, and Form1 is the name of my second form. So i'm trying to send "ime" to my second form named Form1.
In Form1 i got this code:

```
 public string imee { get; set; }
```

Plus a button to test if my string is working:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.imee);
    }
```

It does not work. MessageBox doesn't show anything.

Comment: Where do you show a `Form1`?

Comment: You are probably using a different instance of `Form1` and not the same instance.

Comment: @David I show my Form1 later on.

Comment: @AljažTajhman: "Later on" where?  In the code shown you create an instance of `Form1`, set a value, never show it, and then it immediately falls out of scope because the method ends.  If you're showing a different instance, that's the one where you'll want to set the value.

Answer (score 0):

Usual problem. You are creating a NEW instance of Form1 and it is this instance that receives the string. The Form1 instance actually on your screen is unchanged.

You can fix the problem looking at the OpenForms collection, search for an instance of Form1 and then, if found, pass the string to this instance.

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ime=input_Ime.Text;
    var frm1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
    if(frm1 != null)
        frm1.imee = ime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are opening second form after someone filled out `ime`, so on second form opening you need to do this:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{        
    string ime;

    public Form1(string ime) //with this you are requesting `ime` when creating this form
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.ime = ime; //with this.ime you are referring to variable of this form, and with ime you are referring to variable from function
    }
}
```

And when you are opening this form from `Registracija` you need to do this

`Form1 f1 = new Form1 (ime);`

Comment: This is not the OP's issue. This is a different way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

In Registracija,

```
   public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ime=input_Ime.Text;
            Form1 frm1 = new Form1(ime);
            frm1.show();
        }
```

In Form1,

```
public Form2(string strTextBox)
{
  InitializeComponent(); 
  Messagebox.Show(strTextBox);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. Unless you explain what the issue is, and how your solution addresses it, this will not be very useful to anyone.